# How to ignore special characters except "-" in python3?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Could anyone tell me how should I ignore all special characters except "-" using `isalnum()`. If this is not possible could anyone help me out with its regular expression?

I would like to allow only `['a-z','A-Z',0-9,'-']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the chars you want to allow inside a character class and then make it to repeat one or more times b adding a `+` quantifier next to that character class.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```

**Example:**

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$', 'foo-bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='foo-bar'>
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$', 'Foo9bar')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 7), match='Foo9bar'>
>>> re.match(r'[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$', 'Foo+bar')
>>>
```

Comment: what if I want to ignore empty string and allowing only numbers, letter and dash `[$|a-zA-Z0-9-]+$` is this right?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$` alone won't allow empty strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much wrote the regular expression yourself. If you thoroughly read over [**character classes**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you'll learn that they define a set of characters. Saying — "match **one** of the characters specified by the class". So, all you really need to do is remove the quotations and commas from the character class, precede it with a [**quantifier**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) and [**anchor**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html) the pattern.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
```